# Extract one value from XML in R

Tags: xml, r, geocoding

I'm trying to extract a certain value from some geocoding XML output, but am having trouble getting the final step. Basically, I plug in coordinates into a URL that geocodes the points. I've tried various combinations of xmlParse, xmlTreeParse, xmlRoot, and even changing the output to be JSON. I want *only* the Block FIPS value.

For example, using this location:

```
url = paste("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2000/find?latitude=", "35.8215924013033",
        "&longitude=", "-103.518235473686",
        "&showall=true",
        "&format=xml",sep = "")
```

I've done this:

```
doc = xmlParse(url)
root = xmlRoot(doc)
```

which outputs

```
<Block FIPS="350210001001131"/>
```

That's great, but I need only the number. I've tried grepping it out of the above output, but I get an error saying that it can't be coerced into a character form. In the long run I'll be doing this for hundreds of locations.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I get errors  when I tried `doc = xmlParse(url)#failed to load HTTP resource`

Comment: I changed the url so that it's pasted together. I think dput() changed the spacing or something. Sorry about that!

Comment: Try `unname(xmlAttrs(root[["Block"]]))#[1] "350210001001131"`

Answer (score 0):

Since the API offer a json format, Better to use it to extract data.

```
## the site url 
url = "http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/find?format=json"
## lat & long parameters
lat = 35.8215924013033
long = -103.518235473686
## dynamic url using lat and long 
url = paste0(url,"&latitude=",lat,"&longitude=",long,"&showall=true")
## the API call here    
library(RJSONIO)
dc = fromJSON(url)
## extract the FIPS
dc$Block["FIPS"]

"350210001001368"
```

In case you want to use the XML format :

```
doc = htmlParse(url)  ## use your url here given in the question
xpathSApply(doc,'//*/block',xmlGetAttr,"fips")
[1] "350210001001368"
```

Answer (score 0):

since the `Response` has a namespace:

```
library(XML)

url = paste("http://data.fcc.gov/api/block/2000/find?latitude=", "35.8215924013033",
            "&longitude=", "-103.518235473686",
            "&showall=true",
            "&format=xml",sep = "")


doc = xmlParse(url)

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:Block/@FIPS", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "350210001001131"

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:County/@FIPS", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "35021"

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:County/@name", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "Harding"

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:State/@FIPS", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "35"

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:State/@code", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "NM"

as.character(xpathApply(doc, "//fcc:State/@name", namespaces="fcc"))
## [1] "New Mexico"
```